# How can i convert this button in responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to convert this button in responsive but i don't know how, i want this 4 button display verticaly aligned only on mobile. I didn't find any site for this problem :(. Thank you for all the answer!

```css
.rainbow {
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  right: -3px;
  bottom: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: linear-gradient(124deg, #ff2400, #e81d1d, #e8b71d, #e3e81d, #1de840, #1ddde8, #2b1de8, #dd00f3, #dd00f3);
  background-size: 1800% 1800%;
  -webkit-animation: rainbow 7s ease infinite;
  -z-animation: rainbow 7s ease infinite;
  -o-animation: rainbow 7s ease infinite;
  animation: rainbow 7s ease infinite;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}

.bottoni {
  float: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 7%;
}

.bottone {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 17px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 100% auto;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 200px;
  height: 35px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background: white;
  transform: 1s;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
 -webkit-animation: bottoni 1s ease 0s 1 normal ;
 animation: bottoni 1s ease 0s 1 normal ;
}

.bottone:before {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  top: 100%;
  left: 5%;
  height: 10px;
  width: 90%;
  opacity: 0;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0%, transparent 80%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0%, transparent 80%);
  /* W3C */
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform, opacity;
  transition-property: transform, opacity;
  }

.bottone:hover, .bottone:focus, .bottone:active {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}

 .bottone:hover:before, .bottone:focus:before, .bottone:active:before {
opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
  transform: translateY(10px);
}

/* Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes rainbow {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 82%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 19%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 82%
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes rainbow {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 82%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 19%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 82%
  }
}

@-o-keyframes rainbow {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 82%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 19%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 82%
  }
}

@keyframes rainbow {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 82%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 19%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 82%
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bottoni">
<a class="bottone">
  Votaci
  <div class="rainbow"></div>
</a>

<a class="bottone">
  forum
  <div class="rainbow"></div>
</a>

<a class="bottone">
  regolamento
  <div class="rainbow"></div>
</a>

<a class="bottone">
  shop
  <div class="rainbow"></div>
</a>
</div>
```

All answer are apprecited

Answer (score 1):

You could use absolute position on mobile on `.bottoni` to center your menu verticaly, for the responsive use [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp) :

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .bottoni {
        top: 50%; /* adjust to your needs */
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
}
```

see the : https://jsfiddle.net/s0smLw16/

Comment: @Lafa Have you checked the fiddle? Try resizing the screen and you'll see that it'll align verticaly.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.rainbow {
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  right: -3px;
  bottom: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: linear-gradient(124deg, #ff2400, #e81d1d, #e8b71d, #e3e81d, #1de840, #1ddde8, #2b1de8, #dd00f3, #dd00f3);
  background-size: 1800% 1800%;
  -webkit-animation: rainbow 7s ease infinite;
  -z-animation: rainbow 7s ease infinite;
  -o-animation: rainbow 7s ease infinite;
  animation: rainbow 7s ease infinite;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}

.bottoni {
  float: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 7%;
}

.bottone {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 17px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 100% auto;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 200px;
  height: 35px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background: white;
  transform: 1s;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
 -webkit-animation: bottoni 1s ease 0s 1 normal ;
 animation: bottoni 1s ease 0s 1 normal ;
}

.bottone:before {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  top: 100%;
  left: 5%;
  height: 10px;
  width: 90%;
  opacity: 0;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0%, transparent 80%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0%, transparent 80%);
  /* W3C */
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform, opacity;
  transition-property: transform, opacity;
  }

.bottone:hover, .bottone:focus, .bottone:active {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}

 .bottone:hover:before, .bottone:focus:before, .bottone:active:before {
opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
  transform: translateY(10px);
}

/* Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes rainbow {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 82%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 19%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 82%
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes rainbow {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 82%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 19%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 82%
  }
}

@-o-keyframes rainbow {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 82%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 19%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 82%
  }
}

@keyframes rainbow {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 82%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 19%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 82%
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .bottoni {
    top: 50%; /* adjust to your needs */
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="bottoni">
<a class="bottone">
  Votaci
  <div class="rainbow"></div>
</a>

<a class="bottone">
  forum
  <div class="rainbow"></div>
</a>

<a class="bottone">
  regolamento
  <div class="rainbow"></div>
</a>

<a class="bottone">
  shop
  <div class="rainbow"></div>
</a>
</div>
```

you can use css @media

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px // size of the screen) {}
```

Comment: it's working on my side, how are you testing? resize your screen and you will see the change

Comment: yes but it display like this, i don't know why https://image.prntscr.com/image/lq6-rap7SOuhUFvY5ut-5g.png

Comment: @Lafa what is the screen size of your mobile?

Comment: i don't know is a huawei p8 lite

Comment: use Bootstrap my dear friend

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `@media` selector to your css.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    a.btn {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/qpe2xoem/1/

Comment: he wants the button to be aligned on mobile only, 1000px isn't a mobile screen size